# TeX Live Utility not updating base and/or packages

Tags: texlive

I am not able to do anything with my TexLive manager. Has anyone any idea how I can update my packages again? E.g. this is the output, when I try "Reinstall Package Manager" under "actions":

```
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController updateInfrastructure:][2039] Beginning user-requested infrastructure update…
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _isCorrectDatabaseVersionAtURL:][2039]   Checking database version in case preferences have been changed…
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _updateAllPackagesFromRepository:][2039] Beginning infrastructure update from ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _synchronouslyDownloadURL:toPath:][2039] Downloading URL: ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][2039]    Download redirected to ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh, expecting 0 bytes.
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didFailWithError:][2039]    Download failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x6000000eac00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x60800185e900 "unknown error", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh, NSErrorFailingURLKey=ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh, NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}
Failed URL was: ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
2014-10-22 07:57:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation main][2039]  Removed temp directory "/var/folders/6f/j5bgmczd5mg82y7w6fllrhn80000gp/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.8l4Mh5"
2014-10-22 07:57:56 +0000 Notice -[TLMLogWindowController awakeFromNib][2039]   Loaded log window controller
```

Comment: Try to change the repository. Do you use the GUI?

Comment: In the main menu, go to Configure -> Manage Repositories and choose a different server, preferably http. Do you have a firewall that blocks ftp, by chance?

Comment: I am able to open in Safari other ftp sites as a guest. The http suggestion did the trick.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a temporarily malfunctioning mirror.

Answer (score 0):

Configure -> Manage Repositories and using a http-server solved my problem.